# Convert images to WebP on ASP.NET core

Tags: html, image-processing, asp.net-core, seo

everyone. I am runing Lighthouse Page Speed on my page (https://www.indievisible.net) and it says I should deliver images in a next gen format but I am failing to find a good library to do that for ASP.NET Core.

All I got for now is to import Magick.NET and use the basic optimization with no benefits so far:

```
ImageOptimizer optimizer = new ImageOptimizer();
            optimizer.LosslessCompress(ms);
```

Anyone know a good way to fix this issues with Lighthouse?

Maybe using responsive images instead of next-gen formats?

Thank you all!

Answer (score 0):

Lighthouse is Google. WebP is Google. Google is obviously a little biased. WebP does generally have smaller file sizes, but it's not always significant, and it certainly doesn't mean that you should necessarily WebP all the the things. Additionally, it should be noted that WebP is not universally supported, so it only *really* makes sense when combined with the `picture` element, so you can provide multiple formats. The `picture` element is *also* not universally supported, and it doesn't have native graceful degradation for older browsers like `img` with `srcset` does. The long and short, is that while it may boost the performance of your site a tad, depending on how image heavy it is, it's not in any way a trivial thing to implement. There should be a strong business case to go down this path.

Note also that Lighthouse recommendations are just that: recommendations. Not all of them make sense for every application. It's telling you everything that can be done to make your site faster, but that doesn't mean it makes sense to do every single thing. You need to weight the potential gain against the effort *and* necessity. If you're delivering a fairly light-weight site, already, with only a handful of images, then it's highly unlikely WebP is worth your time. So your uncached page weight would be 500KB vs 600KB. If you're under a MB, your still in much better shape than most sites and that extra 100KB isn't even worth worrying about honestly, especially if it's cached. It's all relative. If you're building the next Flickr, maybe WebP is something worth considering.